# drop down + user input (text)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Hi guys I've looked around and I haven't really gotten a really good answer on this.

So I have a drop down list that allows my users to pick which city they live in and stuff. However I want it so that that drop down has the ability to allow users to first type in their value first or select a value from the drop down.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<div class="atl_form_row">
    <div class="atl_left"><span class="mandatory">*</span>
        <label class="control-label atlFormLabel" for="Service City">Service City/County:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="atl_right">
        <select id="ServiceCity" name="ServiceCity">
            <option value "" disabled selected>Select City/County</option>
            <option value="Alpharetta">Alpharetta</option>
            <option value="Atlanta">Atlanta</option>
            <option value="Brookhaven">Brookhaven</option>
            <option value="Chamblee">Chamblee</option>
            <option value="Chattahoochee Hills">Chattahoochee Hills</option>
            <option value="College Park">College Park</option>
            <option value="Decatur">Decatur</option>
            <option value="Douglasville">Douglasville</option>
            <option value="Duluth">Duluth</option>
            <option value="Dunwoody">Dunwoody</option>
            <option value="East Point">East Point</option>
            <option value="Fairburn">Fairburn</option>
            <option value="Fulton County">Fulton County</option>
            <option value="Hapeville">Hapeville</option>
            <option value="Johns Creek">Johns Creek</option>
            <option value="Marietta">Marietta</option>
            <option value="Milton">Milton</option>
            <option value="Mountain Park">Mountain Park</option>
            <option value="Newnan">Newnan</option>
            <option value="Palmetto">Palmetto</option>
            <option value="Riverdale">Riverdale</option>
            <option value="Roswell">Roswell</option>
            <option value="Sandy Springs">Sandy Springs</option>
            <option value="Smyrna">Smyrna</option>
            <option value="Union City">Union City</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>';
```

Comment: Why don't you just make an input box and a dropdown and give the user a choice of using one or the other

Comment: Something like this? http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: Yea thats kind of what i have now....but its messy and i have to have 2 fields that kind of do the samething. I want to combine the input box and dropdown...any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal here is, but dropdowns let you use your keyboard to select items already. Just highlight a dropdown and then type. It works for windows anyway, I can't say for linux or mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new HTML5 [`<datalist>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) element is what you are looking for:

```
<input list="ServiceCity">
<datalist id="ServiceCity" name="ServiceCity">
            <option value "" disabled selected>Select City/County</option>
            <option value="Alpharetta">Alpharetta</option>
            <option value="Atlanta">Atlanta</option>
            <option value="Brookhaven">Brookhaven</option>
            <option value="Chamblee">Chamblee</option>
            <option value="Chattahoochee Hills">Chattahoochee Hills</option>
            <option value="College Park">College Park</option>
            <option value="Decatur">Decatur</option>
            <option value="Douglasville">Douglasville</option>
            <option value="Duluth">Duluth</option>
            <option value="Dunwoody">Dunwoody</option>
            <option value="East Point">East Point</option>
            <option value="Fairburn">Fairburn</option>
            <option value="Fulton County">Fulton County</option>
            <option value="Hapeville">Hapeville</option>
            <option value="Johns Creek">Johns Creek</option>
            <option value="Marietta">Marietta</option>
            <option value="Milton">Milton</option>
            <option value="Mountain Park">Mountain Park</option>
            <option value="Newnan">Newnan</option>
            <option value="Palmetto">Palmetto</option>
            <option value="Riverdale">Riverdale</option>
            <option value="Roswell">Roswell</option>
            <option value="Sandy Springs">Sandy Springs</option>
            <option value="Smyrna">Smyrna</option>
            <option value="Union City">Union City</option>
        </datalist>
```

As the user types in the `<input>`, the options from the datalist drop down. Or, a double click makes the whole list drop, like a select.

## [See this JSFiddle for a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/ryax5L29/1/)

Comment: Yea this works fine thanks for the answer. However this doesn't fit in with my other fields (style wise) any idea on how i would be able to edit the style of this field? sorry if im coming off as a noob....i really am htough

Comment: The textarea or dropdown?

Comment: The textarea can be easily styled, but to style datalist, you have to use jquery ui :(

Comment: You can do a little styling, input[list] in css [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryax5L29/18/)

Comment: just had a quick look around, There isn't much out there by way of styling datalists. If you really want a good solution then maybe jquery probably has a plugin or something to help. give me 2 minutes as I coded one for myself once, I'll have a look for it

Comment: nope, can't find it.one solution might be to have a standard input box with a hidden styled div below and a js array of towns. with the keydown event in js, grab the key and search the array, add matches to the a array and show the hidden div with the matches inside on new lines. onselect make that the value of the input. The code I had queried the DB each time so wasn't very economical anyway.